# Calculating White streaks

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I was looking at the data structure problem [White Streaks](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1628). 
I am interested to know if there is any known algorithm / data structure to solve this problem. It would be great if someone can please give me some hint regarding data structure/algorithm to solve this.

Comment: The point of online challenges is that _you_ solve them.

Comment: The data-structure I'd go with is.... array.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as a (bipartite) graph problem. If there is a black day in a week, there is an edge between that week and that day of the week. Now just apply data structures designed for storing graphs, such as adjacency matrix or neighbor lists.